# How do I run gshutdown as root?

Tags: 11.10, applet

How do I run gshutdown as root.  In 11.04 , I modified the comand line via the main menu,  by adding, `su-to-root -X -c /usr/bin` before the command line.  I can't find an equivalent to 'main menu' in Oneric.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the Dash and find *GShutdown*. Drag and Drop it from the Dash to your Home folder.
2. Now open a terminal and run the following command to edit the launcher:

   ```
   gedit gshutdown.desktop
   ```
3. Change the text after `Exec=` to your new command:

   [image]
4. Save the file and close it. Now copy the launcher to your local application folder:

   ```
   cp gshutdown.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
5. If you have *GShutdown* on your Launcher, remove it and then launch *GShutdown* from the Dash. You should be prompted for your password as you would expect.